# Cost-sensitive loss function in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, cost-based-optimizer

I'm doing research for cost-sensitive neural network based on Tensorflow. **But because of the static graph structure of Tensorflow. Some NN structure couldn't be realized by myself.**

My loss function(cost) ,cost matrix and the computational progress is described as follow and my target is to compute the total cost and then optimize the NN :

Approximately computational progress:
[image]

- the `y_` is the last full-connect output of a CNN which has shape `(1024,5)`
- the `y` is a Tensor which has shape(1024) and indicates the ground truth of `x[i]`
- the `y_soft[i] [j]` indicates the probability of `x[i]` to be class `j`

How can I realize this in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

cost_matrix:

```
[[0,1,100],
[1,0,1],
[1,20,0]]
```

label:

```
[1,2]
```

y*:

```
[[0,1,0],
[0,0,1]]
```

y(prediction):

```
[[0.2,0.3,0.5],
[0.1,0.2,0.7]]
```

label,cost_matrix-->cost_embedding:

```
[[1,0,1],
[1,20,0]]
```

It obvious 0.3 in [0.2,0.3,0.5] refers to right lable probility of [0,1,0], so it should not contibute to loss.

0.7 in [0.1,0.2,0.7] is the same. In other words, the pos with value 1 in y* not contibute to loss.

So I have (1-y*):

```
[[1,0,1],
[1,1,0]]
```

Then the entropy is target*log(predict) + (1-target) * log(1-predict),and value 0 in y*,should use (1-target)*log(1-predict), so I use (1-predict) said (1-y)

1-y:

```
[[0.8,*0.7*,0.5],
[0.9,0.8,*0.3*]]
```

(italic num is useless)

the custom loss is

```
[[1,0,1], [1,20,0]]   *   log([[0.8,0.7,0.5],[0.9,0.8,0.3]])    *  
[[1,0,1],[1,1,0]]
```

and you can see the (1-y*) can be drop here

so the loss is -tf.reduce_mean(cost_embedding*log(1-y))
,to make it applicable , should be:

```
-tf.reduce_mean(cost_embedding*log(tf.clip((1-y),1e-10)))
```

the demo is below

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
hidden_units = 50
num_class = 3
class Model():
    def __init__(self,name_scope,is_custom):
        self.name_scope = name_scope
        self.is_custom = is_custom
        self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,hidden_units])
        self.input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None])

        self.instantiate_weights()
        self.logits = self.inference()
        self.predictions = tf.argmax(self.logits,axis=1)
        self.losses,self.train_op = self.opitmizer()

    def instantiate_weights(self):
        with tf.variable_scope(self.name_scope + 'FC'):
            self.W = tf.get_variable('W',[hidden_units,num_class])
            self.b = tf.get_variable('b',[num_class])

            self.cost_matrix = tf.constant(
                np.array([[0,1,100],[1,0,100],[20,5,0]]),
                dtype = tf.float32
            )

    def inference(self):
        return tf.matmul(self.input_x,self.W) + self.b

    def opitmizer(self):
        if not self.is_custom:
            loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits\
                (labels=self.input_y,logits=self.logits)
        else:
            batch_cost_matrix = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
                self.cost_matrix,self.input_y
            )
            loss = - tf.log(1 - tf.nn.softmax(self.logits))\
                     * batch_cost_matrix

        train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
        return loss,train_op

import random
batch_size = 128
norm_model = Model('norm',False)
custom_model = Model('cost',True)
split_point = int(0.9 * dataset_size)
train_set = datasets[:split_point]
test_set = datasets[split_point:]


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(100):
        batch_index = random.sample(range(split_point),batch_size)
        train_batch = train_set[batch_index]
        train_labels = lables[batch_index]
        _,eval_predict,eval_loss = sess.run([norm_model.train_op,
                  norm_model.predictions,norm_model.losses],
                  feed_dict={
                      norm_model.input_x:train_batch,
                      norm_model.input_y:train_labels
        })
        _,eval_predict1,eval_loss1 = sess.run([custom_model.train_op,
                  custom_model.predictions,custom_model.losses],
                  feed_dict={
                      custom_model.input_x:train_batch,
                      custom_model.input_y:train_labels
        })
        # print 'norm',eval_predict,'\ncustom',eval_predict1
        print np.sum(((eval_predict == train_labels)==True).astype(np.int)),\
            np.sum(((eval_predict1 == train_labels)==True).astype(np.int))
        if i%10 == 0:
            print  'norm_test',sess.run(norm_model.predictions,
                  feed_dict={
                      norm_model.input_x:test_set,
                      norm_model.input_y:lables[split_point:]
        })
            print  'custom_test',sess.run(custom_model.predictions,
                  feed_dict={
                      custom_model.input_x:test_set,
                      custom_model.input_y:lables[split_point:]
        })
```